# Is there a better way to accomplish this function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Recently I discovered a book named "*Automate The Boring Stuff With Python*". I came to a practice exercise which says,

> Write a function that takes a list value as an argument and returns a
> string with all the items separated by a comma and a space, with `and`
> inserted before the last item. For example, passing the previous spam
> list to the function would return `'apples, bananas, tofu, and cats'`.
> But your function should be able to work with any list value passed to
> it.

I made this code but I believe there is a better way to do it. What is the easiest way this can be done?

```
def list_manu(lst):
  spam[-1] = 'and '+spam[-1]
  new_spam=[] 
  x = ','.join(spam)
  return f"'{x}'"  

spam = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu','here','here', 'cats']
print(list_manu(spam))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This program takes care of the [Oxford comma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma) -

```
def list_manu(spam):
   if not spam:
      return "Your list is empty!"

   elif len(spam) == 1:
      return f"'{spam[0]}'"

   elif len(spam) == 2:
      return f"'{spam[0]} and {spam[1]}'"

   else:
      body = ", ".join(map(str, spam[:-1]))
      return f"'{body}, and {spam[-1]}'"
    
spam = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'here', 'here', 'cats']
print(list_manu(spam))
```

Output:

```
'apples, bananas, tofu, here, here, and cats'
```

---

This program doesn't take care of the Oxford comma, but it suits the purpose of your given task -

```
def list_manu(spam):
   if len(spam) == 1:
      return f"'{spam[0]}'"

   body = ", ".join(map(str, spam[:-1]))  
   return f"'{body}, and {spam[-1]}'"
    
spam = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'here', 'here', 'cats']
print(list_manu(spam))
```

Output:

```
'apples, bananas, tofu, here, here, and cats'
```

Comment: @seprico No problem! I've edited my answer to include some more details, check it out..

Comment: they both great , thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could join the last two elements with " and " and join that with the preceding elements using commas:

```
# without Oxford comma (e.g. French punctuation)
def list_manu(lst):
    return ", ".join(lst[:-2]+[" and ".join(lst[-2:])])

# with Oxford comma (uses ', and ' when size is 3+)
def list_manu(lst):
    return ", ".join(lst[:-2]+[", and "[len(lst)<3:].join(lst[-2:])])
```

output:

```
spam = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu','here','here', 'cats']

list_manu(spam)   # 'apples, bananas, tofu, here, here, and cats'

# works with all list sizes
list_manu([])                            # ''
list_manu(['apple'])                     # 'apple'
list_manu(['apple','oranges'])           # 'apple and oranges'
list_manu(['apple','oranges','bananas']) # 'apple, oranges, and bananas'
```

Comment: this looks far simpler to understand